# fuse parsing custom arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, fuse

Using libfuse in my c-project, I 'm trying to add custom command-line arguments and handle them.

Here is an example on which I rely

https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Option-Parsing

First, I tried to do the argument for the mount point configuration `-с <pathtoconfig>`

I tried many ways to describe an option like `-c --config conf= -o conf=`, but ineffectually

Please, help me find the right path to solve the problem :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fuse.h>

#include "fuu_walk.h"
#include "jsmnload.h"

#define _JSMN_TOKEN_SIZE_   256
#define _JSMN_BUFFER_SIZE_  4096
#define MYFS_OPT(t, p, v) { t, offsetof(struct myfs_config, p), v }

struct myfs_config {
    char *mystring;
} conf;

static struct fuse_opt myfs_opts[] = {
    MYFS_OPT("-c %s", mystring, 1),

    FUSE_OPT_END
};

jsmntok_t   t[_JSMN_TOKEN_SIZE_];
char        buf[_JSMN_BUFFER_SIZE_];
#if 0
= ""
"{\"root\": ["
    "{\"path\":\"/\", \"mode\":\"drw-------\"},"
    "{\"path\":\"/12ABC345DE67\", \"mode\":\"drw-------\"},"
    "{\"path\":\"/12ABC345DE67/_XQ01\", \"mode\":\"-rw-------\"},"
    "{\"path\":\"/12ABC345DE67/_XQ02\", \"mode\":\"-rw-------\"},"
    "{\"path\":\"/12ABC345DE78\", \"mode\":\"drw-------\"},"
    "{\"path\":\"/12ABC345DE89\", \"mode\":\"drw-------\"}"
"]}";
#endif


static int myfs_opt_proc(void *data, const char *arg, int key, struct fuse_args *outargs)
{
    struct myfs_config *ptr = (struct myfs_config *)data;
    FILE *conf;
    int rc = 0; 

//I wanna check the argument on the each iteration of fuse_opt_parse. It's just the debug printf
    printf("arg = %s\t string %s\t key = %i\n", arg, ptr->mystring, key);
    switch (key) {
        case 1:
            conf = fopen(ptr->mystring, "r");
            rc = read(fileno(conf), buf, _JSMN_BUFFER_SIZE_);

            if ( jsmnload(buf, t, _JSMN_TOKEN_SIZE_, fuu_mkfstree) < 0 ) {
                printf("Error load configuration\n");
                exit(-1);
            }

    }

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct fuse_args args = FUSE_ARGS_INIT(argc, argv);

    memset(&conf, 0, sizeof(conf));

    fuse_opt_parse(&args, &conf, myfs_opts, myfs_opt_proc);

    return fuu_main(args.argc, args.argv);
}
```

Launch example

```
./appendix/fuu /mnt/cdrom/ -c /mnt/fs.json
```

As a result, printf in myfs_opt_proc function works only once and outputs

```
arg = /mnt/cdrom/        string (null)   key = -2
```

Why myfs_opt_proc does not work for option -c?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment so as an answer... looking at the reference you provided it seems to me that there is no option starting with `-c`. So result seems correct because fuse cannot parse this. Look at this snippet from your link:

```
fuse_opt_add_arg(&args, "-omodules=subdir,subdir=/foo");
```

You may try to announce options to fuse using `-o`.

---

Edit: Youre example differs from the linked one, try to add to following line to the defined `struct`:

```
FUSE_OPT_KEY("-c", "KEY_CONFIG");
```

and some line before

```
emum {
    KEY_CONFIG
};
```

and parse it like this in youre `myfs_opt_proc` function

```
switch (key) {
    case KEY_CONFIG:
        /* ... */
```

. Summed up you missed declaring the `-c` key.

Comment: I think you're right. `MYFS_OPT` belongs to `-o`. Maybe `FUSE_OPT_KEY` might help

Comment: If I use `FUSE_OPT_KEY`, output is `arg = /mnt/cdrom/        string (null)   key = -2
arg = -c         string (null)   key = -1
arg = /media/sf_work_134/fuseuse/appendix/fs.json        string (null)   key = -2`. It looks like I need to use `fuse_opt_add_arg`, but I cant unterstand how it works

Comment: I think that `FUSE_OPT_KEY` just overloads existing options, but i want to create my custom option